# Windows 8 Live Tiles Update Every Minute

Tags: windows-8, live-tile

Is it possible to change a Live Tile image every minute?
I looked at background and push services, and that seems to be limited to 15 minutes...

Answer (score 2):

You can set a tile using the Tile Update locally at any time, and clear it etc. This can only happen when your app is running.

However, you are able to call that API from your background worker.

The API you need is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.update.aspx

Push Notifications can happen at any time, and have *expirary* times, which I think the default is 15mins.

Apps such as Mail push more than one notification every 15mins.

For a more in-depth look at the background worker model in Windows 8 Store apps, see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411)

Comment: I got the background service working now. Problem: There seems to be no reliable way to just run it right away. I need the tile updated once a minute. But using a TimeTrigger(set to 1 minute) the background service might take up to 16 minutes to respond.(according to documentation). Is there any other way I can make sure a background service is already running after my app has started(or paused)? After that I can probably handle the Timer settings from there.

Comment: The communication between background service and apps is a royal pain. There's no simple intrinsic way; you'll need to either write a file and load that up / watch change notifications on that file. The other option is to use Named Pipes between the two processes.

Comment: What do you mean by named pipes communication? Is there any sample I can use? I thought if the app is paused there is no client running anyway. Or is it possible to "wake up" the paused app using a remote call(background/push service)?

Comment: an app that is suspended can only be activated by an explicit user action.

Your background app does get woken up periodically; the whitepaper I added to my answer has lots of details about the heuristics here.

For named pipes; you need to look at either the C# implementation, or C++ of named pipes to create a projection that javascript can make us of if you aren't using C# (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411 has some info)

Comment: There is an excellent clock example written by Dave Smits ['here is the source'](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff/view/Discussions#content) it shows what is required.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a search on Google, I have found this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411.

I hope you can get the answer or information regarding your problem there.

Comment: Just in case the link dies, bring some of the ideas there. :)

Comment: Since this isn't really a complete answer to the question, it should probably be a comment instead of an answer. Also, it's regarded as good etiquette to briefly summarize the contents of links when you post them.

Comment: Since there is not comments, and the link now is dead, this should no longer be an answer.

Comment: This is the most recent archived version of that link, before Microsoft took it down: https://web.archive.org/web/20160331161542/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411